# how can i show a misinput in CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i been doing a menu for my class in cmd and i cant make something like a if else structure for it , so even if i give him a wrong input it wont even show a message on the screen, someone know what i can do in this ?

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO presione su eleccion :1,2 o 3 para salir
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - Copia de seguridad y ruta de guardado del respaldo 
ECHO 2 - Cambio de extension de un archivo
ECHO 3 - Salir
ECHO.
ECHO.
SET /P M=presione 1,2 o 3 y presione enter:
IF %M%==1 (GOTO RESPALDO)
ELSE IF %M%==2 (GOTO EXTENSION)
ELSE IF %M%==3 (GOTO EOF)
ELSE (ECHO Opcion no valida 
GOTO MENU)

:RESPALDO
cd %windir%\system32\notepad.exe
start notepad.exe
GOTO MENU
:EXTENSION
cd %windir%\system32\calc.exe
start calc.exe
GOTO MENU
```

Comment: `ELSE` is not a command in its own right, it is part of the `IF` command. As such it must be part of the `IF` command line itself, not on a separate unconnected line. As a side note, you should not be using `SET /P` for known single input keys, there is a `CHOICE` command, designed especially for that. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `choice /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, to find out how to use it.

Comment: The `IF...ELSE` syntax is clearly explained in the help file for the `IF` command. Your code clearly shows that you did not read the help file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ELSE` must be in the "same" line as the `IF` (maybe extended by parenthesis `()`). So you could write something like this:

```
IF %M%==1 (GOTO RESPALDO) else (
IF %M%==2 (GOTO EXTENSION) else (
IF %M%==3 (GOTO :EOF) else (
ECHO Opcion no valida 
GOTO MENU
)
)
)
```

But in this example, you could also dismiss the `ELSE`:

```
IF %M%==1 (GOTO RESPALDO)
IF %M%==2 (GOTO EXTENSION)
IF %M%==3 (GOTO :EOF)
ECHO Opcion no valida 
GOTO MENU
```

BTW: The `GOTO :EOF` must have the colon, if not it is not found.